# MMC could not create the snap-in

Tags: windows-xp, windows

When trying to run the Group policy I get the above message. (MMC could not create the snap-in) Several systems are affected, all WinXP with SP3 and latest updates.

Any ideas on how to get the editor back to working mode ?

I get a CLSID: `{8FC0B734-A0E1-11D1-A7D3-0000F87571E3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

> %SystemRoot%\System32\WBEM

To your PATH in Environment Variables.

[Here's the link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/826282)

Comment: thanks a lot !! solved my problem in an instant. Don't know how I missed it, after all I spent a whole day going through MS KB articles searching for this :-(, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Dror: You might have missed the KB article because it does not include the exact error message text "MMC could not create the snap-in"

It only mentions "Snap-in failed to initialize" (which, now, this topic does too).

Breck

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is because of Microsoft .NET Framework. So far it's turned off, so you need to turn it on via `Turn Windows features on or off`. Simply navigate to `Control Panel` > `Programs and Features` > `Turn Windows features On or Off`. Select the checkbox for `Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5` and apply. If you are still facing any difficulty then post back or go through [this](https://validedge.com/mmc-could-not-create-the-snap-in/) guide.

Answer (score 0):

To add `%SystemRoot%\System32\WBEM` in your PATH, `setx PATH "%PATH%;%SystemRoot%\System32\WBEM"`.